# css not reflecting on all classes on html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page with html and css and possibly some php but I'm having some unexpected issues with css and I'm out of ideas.

```
<h1>X-Corp</h1>
<p class="hp">
    <b><i>Dominating and Redefining IT</i></b>
</p>
<div class=contact>
    <p>email: bigchuk00@gmail.com</p>
    <p>Tel : +2348062202958</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="page1">In this ever-evolving world we live in, the growth of
        IT related problems is always on the rise. Thats where we come in.
        With our top-notch engineers, IT gurus, system analysts and
        impecceble graphics team, we devote our 110% time and effort to be
        there for you, lending a hand to solving all your IT related issues.
    </p>

    <p class="page2">
        Are you a techie or just someone who desires to acquire an IT related
        device or material and dont know how? Search no more because WE at
        X-Corp have just completed international pertnership plans and
        contract to ensure we help you seamlessly to achieve that technically
        challenging objective of yours. Be it building a gaming rig, a server
        powerhouse, that geeky crib you've been dreaming of, or even getting
        your full scale company or organisation up to date with the latest in
        the IT world, believe me, we got you covered. <a href="ourcmd.php">Read
            more</a>

    </p>
</div>
</body>
```

but everything from the h1 tag to the page1 class will not accept some of the values in css.
This is the css code:

```
.page1
{color : black;
background : e3e3e3;
margin : left;
widrh : 200px;
float : rightt;
}

.page2
{color : black; 
background-color : e3e3e3;
width : 200px;
margin : left;
float : right;}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Just started learning CSS.

Comment: You are missing a `#` in front of the color hex code ! it should be like `#e3e3e3`

Comment: side note, while this may work: `<div class=contact>` you should quote attributes for consistency and compatibility. `<div class="contact">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost all of your css is invalid.

```
.page1
{
color : black;
background : e3e3e3; <- should be #e3e3e3
margin : left; <- should be a readable value. like margin: 0 10px 0 5px
widrh : 200px; <- should be width
float : rightt; <- should be right
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUn42/) with some fixes. I made some assumptions about what you wanted, but you can play with it at the link by hitting "Run" after you make a change. Some of the mistakes were you need a # in front of the hex colors, margin doesn't take "left", it takes something like "0px" or "20px". The "auto" makes it centered. You also had misspelled a few words.

```
.page1 {
    color : black;
    background : #e3e3e3;
    margin : 0px auto;
    width : auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.page2 {
    color : black; 
    background-color : #e3e3e3;
    width : auto;
    margin : 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- In the CSS for `.page1` you wrote `rightt` instead of `right`.
- Use `background-color: #e3e3e3` instead of `background : e3e3e3;` (also for `.page1`)
- Use `background-color: #e3e3e3;` instead of `background-color : e3e3e3;` in the CSS for `.page2`